# Writing a Blob in PHP to a SQL Server using MSSQL

Tags: php, sql-server, apache-flex, blob

I have a set of AMFPHP services which receive from a Flex application a bytearray containing an image. So far so good. Now I need to write the bytearray to a blob field in a SQL Server database. I am using the MSSQL library and I cannot change that. How can I do that?

Comment: What code do you have now for the byte array in PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below the solution:

```
// Stores bytearray received from a Flex app through AMPPHP

$arrData = unpack("H*hex", $image->data);
$content = "0x".$arrData['hex'];

$sql = "insert into Images (Id, ImageData) values ($id, $content)";
mssql_query($sql);
```